# Java Random method inside a Constructor not working

Tags: java, algorithm, class, random, uml

Im using a UML class diagram and The program is about playing black jack, I havent wrote the driver file yet but someone told me i needed to put a random method in my default class. Below is my code. the public Card() is my default class and I need to put a random method into it and im not sure how I should go about it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Card
{

private final int MAX = 13;
private int face, suit, points, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Ace, Jack, Queen, King;
//CONSTRUCTORS

public Card() {
    random.newCard();
    }

public Card(int faceValue,int suitValue) {
        //face
        Ace = 1;
        Jack = 11;
        Queen = 12;
        King = 13;

        //suit
        Hearts = 1;
        Diamonds = 2;
        Clubs = 3;
        Spades = 4;

    }

//^^^^^^^
//Mutators

public void setFace(int face)
{
    this.face = face;
 }

public void setSuit(int suit)
{
    this.suit = suit;
}


//Accessors

public int getFace()
{
    return face;}

public int getSuit()
{
    return suit;}

public int getPoints()
{
    return points;}



//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

public String toString()
    {
        return "Players cards are " + " ";

    }

}
```

Comment: `Random random = new Random(MAX); random.nextInt();` This is how it works...

Comment: "public String  toString()" is a method that you already have in your class and your "random" method can be declared the same way. Before that you need to determine what parameters this method will accept and what will it return depending upon what does this random method do

Comment: Learn to look up the javadocs and learn how to read and understand them

Comment: Why are you passing arguments to your constructor when you dont use them?

Comment: I am not done yet, i actually have no clue how Im suppose to use them, this is my first java class and our book is utter crap and were not allowed to use other documents to learn things from according to our teacher

Answer (score 1):

I guess...

> Math.random()

is more helpful to you.

```
int(Math.random()) % 13 + 1; //==> 1 ~ 13

int(Math.random()) % 4 + 1; //==> 1 ~ 4
```

or

```
random.nextInt(12) + 1; //==> 1 ~ 13

random.nextInt(3) + 1; //==> 1 ~ 4
```

will be working.

Answer (score 0):

First we define what is a Card:

```
public class Card
{
    public final int FACE_Ace = 1;
    public final int FACE_Two = 2;
    public final int FACE_Three = 3;
    public final int FACE_Four = 4;
    public final int FACE_Five = 5;
    public final int FACE_Six = 6;
    public final int FACE_Seven = 7;
    public final int FACE_Eight = 8;
    public final int FACE_Nine = 9;
    public final int FACE_Ten = 10;
    public final int FACE_Jack = 11;
    public final int FACE_Queen = 12;
    public final int FACE_King = 13;

    public final int SUIT_Spades = 1;
    public final int SUIT_Clubs = 2;
    public final int SUIT_Diamonds = 3;
    public final int SUIT_Hearts = 4;

    public int face;
    public int suit;

    public Card (int suit, int face)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.face = face;
    }
}
```

Then we have a complete set of Cards in a Deck:

```
public class Deck
{
    private Card[] cards;

    private Random random;

    public Card()
    {
        cards = new Card[52]; // 13 x 4

        // fill in all cards
        for (int suit=1; suit<=4; suit++)
            for (int face=1; face<=13; face++)
                cards[(suit*13)+face-1] = new Card (suit,face);

        // seed using Time
        // keeping Random enhance shuffle entropy over usage
        random = new Random (System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public shuffle ()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<52; i++)
            swap(i, random.nextInt(52)); // [0, 51]
    }

    private void swap (int a, int b)
    {
        Card temp = new Card (cards[a].suit, cards[a].face);

        cards[a].suit = cards[b].suit;
        cards[a].face = cards[b].face;

        cards[b].suit = temp.suit;
        cards[b].face = temp.face;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't use the arrays, the random card has no use for you, for you can't check if you had already created it or not.

The only usable variant is a random permutation. You need an algorithm, that will generate numbers from 1 to 52, non repeating itself.

```
class RandomPermutation{
    int base=1;
    int next(){
        int result;
        do{
            base=base*125 /4096;
            int result=(base-1)/4;
        } while (1<=result<=54)

        return result;
    }
}
```

This sequence can generate 0..1023 permutated. You can change the permutation setting the start base value and range you are allowing.